# Getting comments from tables, functions and views in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a better solution to check all my tables and function descriptions within a project. let's say the code of a function looks something like this:

```
USE [db_name]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      lechnerio
-- Create date: 17.01.2022
-- Description: a very good description
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Name]( 
    @value int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN (
    SELECT * from table where value = @value
);
```

Is there a way to select the comments within a table and/or function in SQL Server? For the code above I'm looking for a way to extract the comments like Author, Created date or Description.

We are selecting all tables, views and function using the `SYSOBJECTS` selection.

```
SELECT name 
FROM SYSOBJECTS
WHERE xtype in ('U', 'FN', 'IF', 'V');
```

but I'd like to get a return that looks something similar to

```
name    | type     | author    | create date | description
--------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------
fn_name | function | lechnerio | 17.01.2022  | a very good description
```

Is there a way to achieve a select like this?

Comment: What do you mean "archive a select"? That *suggests* you want to store it somewhere; if so you would just use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM...`.

Comment: further down the line I want to call said select every one in a while. but for now, I want to manage to get the comments from saved tables, functions and views. 
(sorry, not an english native, I meant "achieve")

Comment: use the `[definition]` column from `sys.sql_modules` to scan procedures for some string, I would use '-- ====' in your case, then you can do logic to bering the next lines

Comment: looks almost like what I'm looking for. figured out that you can run `exec sp_helptext 'fn_name'` to get the return split by lines. looping through all tables and only selecting the values where the line actually starts with `--` seems like a way to go here.

Comment: I would not try this type of parsing in T-SQL but it seems to be exactly what TSqlFragmentVisitor was designed for. I show a couple other uses in [this series](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/10/sql-performance/paramparser-3) and [this series](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6936/find-problematic-sql-nolock-patterns-update-delete/?utm_source=AaronBertrand). Also don’t use `sysobjects` as it’s been deprecated for 17 years.

Answer (score 0):

You could use extended properties in place of comments. But in my experience, this is a bit of a headache to maintain. You can have as many comments (extended properties) as you like for each object. It is best to define a default set of expected properties and ensure that they are maintained over time. This approach allows you to create a living document for your data dictionary. It works the majority of object types in sql see docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Person(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100)
);
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty   
    @name = N'Description',   
    @value = N'A description of the person table',   
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = 'dbo',  
    @level1type = N'TABLE',  @level1name = 'Person';  
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty   
    @name = N'Create Date',   
    @value = N'2022-01-17',   
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = 'dbo',  
    @level1type = N'TABLE',  @level1name = 'Person';  
GO

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty  
     @name = N'Description' 
    ,@value = N'A description of name column on the person table' 
    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'dbo' 
    ,@level1type = N'Table',  @level1name = 'Person' 
    ,@level2type = N'Column', @level2name = 'Name'
GO

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty  
     @name = N'Create Date' 
    ,@value = N'2022-01-17' 
    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'dbo' 
    ,@level1type = N'Table',  @level1name = 'Person' 
    ,@level2type = N'Column', @level2name = 'Name'
GO

-- ---------------------------------------

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetPerson(@Id INT)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM dbo.Person WHERE Id = @Id
END
GO

EXEC sp_addextendedproperty  
     @name = N'Description' 
    ,@value = N'A description about the Foo procedure' 
    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'dbo' 
    ,@level1type = N'Procedure',  @level1name = 'Foo' 
GO

-- ---------------------------------------


DECLARE  @schema_name SYSNAME = 'dbo'
DECLARE  @table_name SYSNAME = 'Person'

SELECT  SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS SchemaName, 
        t.name AS TableName, 
        c.name AS ColumnName,
        p.name AS ExtendedPropertyName,
        CAST(p.value AS sql_variant) AS ExtendedPropertyValue
FROM    sys.tables t
        INNER JOIN sys.all_columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties p ON  p.major_id = t.object_id 
                                             AND p.minor_id = c.column_id 
                                             AND p.class=1
WHERE   SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)=@schema_name
AND     t.name=@table_name
  

SELECT  SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS SchemaName, 
        t.name AS TableName, 
        p.name AS ExtendedPropertyName,
        CAST(p.value AS sql_variant) AS ExtendedPropertyValue
FROM    sys.tables t
        INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties p ON  p.major_id = t.object_id 
                                             AND p.minor_id = 0
                                             AND p.class=1
WHERE   SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)=@schema_name
AND     t.name=@table_name
GO

DECLARE  @schema_name SYSNAME = 'dbo'
DECLARE  @object_name SYSNAME = 'foo'

SELECT  SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS SchemaName, 
        o.name AS ProcedureName, 
        p.name AS ExtendedPropertyName,
        CAST(p.value AS sql_variant) AS ExtendedPropertyValue
FROM    sys.procedures o
        INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties p ON  p.major_id = o.object_id 
                                             AND p.minor_id = 0
                                             AND p.class=1
WHERE   SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)=@schema_name
AND     o.name=@object_name
```